# Android, Espresso test can't work with activity write on Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-espresso

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.3
com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
```

Workflow:

1. Fragment has list view (news)
2. When click on some item on list then open activity (NewsDetailsActivity) that show news details with title "Single news"

Fragment's code:

```
Integer newsId = 1234;
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewsDetailsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(NewsDetailsActivity.ID newsId);
startActivity(intent);
```

NewsDetailsActivity's java code:

```
public class NewsDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        setContentView(R.layout.news_details);
        int newsID = 0;
        String mainCaption = "";
        if (extras != null) {
            newsID = extras.getInt(SELECTED_NEWS_ID);
            mainCaption = extras.getString(SELECTED_NEWS);
        }
        titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        mainNewsDetailsContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainNewsDetailsContainer);
        mainCaptionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainCaptionTextView);
}
```

When activity is open it's title is "**Single news**".
Here screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBFc7.png)

So work fine. OK.

So I write Android Espresso test:

```
 @Test
 public void newsDetailsTitle() {
    // click on listView item and as result open NewsDetailsActivity
   onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.containerNotEmptyListView)).atPosition(NEWS_LIST_POSITION).perform(click());
    // test that title of NewsDetailsActivity is "Single news"
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.titleTextView), withText(R.string.news_single))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
```

And it's passed and work fine. OK.

So now we rewrite NewsDetailsActivity on language Kotlin.

NewsDetailsActivity's Kotlin code:

```
   class NewsDetailsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        verticalLayout {
            include<View>(R.layout.toolbar)
            find<TextView>(R.id.titleTextView).setText(R.string.single_news)
            setSupportActionBar(find<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar))
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        }
    }
}
```

When I start application all work fine. News details open and show title "**Single news"**. OK.

But when I start test the title of NewsDetailsActivity now is NOT "**Single news**". Its absolute another title = "**Recomendation**".

Here screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO0Pu.png)

As result test fail. The key **R.string.news_single** was not changed.

Why title of news detalis was changed?